# Getting current IpluginContext or IorganizationService object in IClientMessageInspector

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm developing a plugin that calls another application WCF service and parses the response. Everything works as expected, but I'm facing many problems when it comes to log the xml messages.

I used an Interceptor, with the following signature:

```
public class SFACMessageInspector : IEndpointBehavior, IClientMessageInspector
```

The following methods must be implemented:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request,IClientChannel channel)
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply,object correlationState)
```

In the methods I retrieve the xml messages with no problem, but now I need to log them, so it has been asked to me to create a new Logger entity that has both the request and the response on two fields.

The big problem is I don't have any of the following objects:

```
IOrganizationService service //this is the object I could use to create the entity
IPluginExecutionContext context  //the context of the plugin, from this I can create a new IorganizationService
```

Being an interceptor there's no way I can pass them as a parameter, so I thought about 2 choices, both of them not giving me the expected results:

- Declaring the service, or the context, as a static class variable (from the plugin calling class, for example), so I can access it from the Inspector. I don't really like this approach, as the context is the less static object I can think of, and it could give problems in a multi-user environment as CRM is.
- Creating a new IOrganizationService object given a string connection parameter. The only working object I found is on the `Microsoft.Xrm.Client` library, that unfortunately is deprecated, where I can create a new object like:

var _service = new OrganizationService(CrmConnection.Parse(CRMConnectionString));

I used this without problems for a month or so, but migrating my Dynamics CRM to 2016 version, this doesn't work anymore. When the code is `LogIntegrationMessage` method, where the service gets created, is called, the following exception gets raised with the following generic error message:

```
Inner Exception: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.InvalidPluginExecutionException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
```

What could I do? Is there any other way to create an instance in a Interceptor class, where I don't have the PluginContext or the OrganizationService?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Event in CRM 2016 you should be able to manually connect to CRM using plain old OrganizationServiceProxy class (in fact the OrganizationService class you were using was just a wrapper over this class). Back in CRM 2011 we were all connecting to CRM like that and there are plenty of examples over the net. CRM SDK (all versions since 2011, 2016 has the same) under "\SDK\SampleCode\CS\GeneralProgramming\Authentication\AuthenticateWithNoHelp\AuthenticateWithNoHelp.cs" provides a great example how you can do the authentication:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;

namespace Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Demonstrate how to do basic authentication using IServiceManagement and SecurityTokenResponse.
    /// </summary>
    class AuthenticateWithNoHelp
    {
        #region Class Level Members
        // To get discovery service address and organization unique name, 
        // Sign in to your CRM org and click Settings, Customization, Developer Resources.
        // On Developer Resource page, find the discovery service address under Service Endpoints and organization unique name under Your Organization Information.
        private String _discoveryServiceAddress = "https://dev.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc";
        private String _organizationUniqueName = "OrganizationUniqueName";
        // Provide your user name and password.
        private String _userName = "username@mydomain.com";
        private String _password = "password"
    #endregion Class Level Members

    #region How To Sample Code
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void Run()
    {
        //<snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp1>
        IServiceManagement<IDiscoveryService> serviceManagement =
                    ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IDiscoveryService>(
                    new Uri(_discoveryServiceAddress));
        AuthenticationProviderType endpointType = serviceManagement.AuthenticationType;

        // Set the credentials.
        AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = GetCredentials(serviceManagement, endpointType);


        String organizationUri = String.Empty;
        // Get the discovery service proxy.
        using (DiscoveryServiceProxy discoveryProxy =
            GetProxy<IDiscoveryService, DiscoveryServiceProxy>(serviceManagement, authCredentials))
        {
            // Obtain organization information from the Discovery service. 
            if (discoveryProxy != null)
            {
                // Obtain information about the organizations that the system user belongs to.
                OrganizationDetailCollection orgs = DiscoverOrganizations(discoveryProxy);
                // Obtains the Web address (Uri) of the target organization.
                organizationUri = FindOrganization(_organizationUniqueName,
                    orgs.ToArray()).Endpoints[EndpointType.OrganizationService];

            }
        }
        //</snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp1>


        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(organizationUri))
        {
            //<snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp3>
            IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> orgServiceManagement =
                ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService>(
                new Uri(organizationUri));

            // Set the credentials.
            AuthenticationCredentials credentials = GetCredentials(orgServiceManagement, endpointType);

            // Get the organization service proxy.
            using (OrganizationServiceProxy organizationProxy =
                GetProxy<IOrganizationService, OrganizationServiceProxy>(orgServiceManagement, credentials))
            {
                // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
                organizationProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

                // Now make an SDK call with the organization service proxy.
                // Display information about the logged on user.
                Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)organizationProxy.Execute(
                    new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
                SystemUser systemUser = organizationProxy.Retrieve("systemuser", userid,
                    new ColumnSet(new string[] { "firstname", "lastname" })).ToEntity<SystemUser>();
                Console.WriteLine("Logged on user is {0} {1}.",
                    systemUser.FirstName, systemUser.LastName);
            }
            //</snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp3>
        }

    }

    //<snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp2>
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtain the AuthenticationCredentials based on AuthenticationProviderType.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service">A service management object.</param>
    /// <param name="endpointType">An AuthenticationProviderType of the CRM environment.</param>
    /// <returns>Get filled credentials.</returns>
    private AuthenticationCredentials GetCredentials<TService>(IServiceManagement<TService> service, AuthenticationProviderType endpointType)
    {
        AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();

        switch (endpointType)
        {
            case AuthenticationProviderType.ActiveDirectory:
                authCredentials.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential =
                    new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_userName,
                        _password,
                        _domain);
                break;
            case AuthenticationProviderType.LiveId:
                authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _userName;
                authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password;
                authCredentials.SupportingCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();
                authCredentials.SupportingCredentials.ClientCredentials =
                    Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.LoadOrRegisterDevice();
                break;
            default: // For Federated and OnlineFederated environments.                    
                authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _userName;
                authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password;
                // For OnlineFederated single-sign on, you could just use current UserPrincipalName instead of passing user name and password.
                // authCredentials.UserPrincipalName = UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName;  // Windows Kerberos

                // The service is configured for User Id authentication, but the user might provide Microsoft
                // account credentials. If so, the supporting credentials must contain the device credentials.
                if (endpointType == AuthenticationProviderType.OnlineFederation)
                {
                    IdentityProvider provider = service.GetIdentityProvider(authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName);
                    if (provider != null && provider.IdentityProviderType == IdentityProviderType.LiveId)
                    {
                        authCredentials.SupportingCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();
                        authCredentials.SupportingCredentials.ClientCredentials =
                            Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.LoadOrRegisterDevice();
                    }
                }

                break;
        }

        return authCredentials;
    }
    //</snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp2>

    /// <summary>
    /// Discovers the organizations that the calling user belongs to.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service">A Discovery service proxy instance.</param>
    /// <returns>Array containing detailed information on each organization that 
    /// the user belongs to.</returns>
    public OrganizationDetailCollection DiscoverOrganizations(
        IDiscoveryService service)
    {
        if (service == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
        RetrieveOrganizationsRequest orgRequest = new RetrieveOrganizationsRequest();
        RetrieveOrganizationsResponse orgResponse =
            (RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)service.Execute(orgRequest);

        return orgResponse.Details;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds a specific organization detail in the array of organization details
    /// returned from the Discovery service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orgUniqueName">The unique name of the organization to find.</param>
    /// <param name="orgDetails">Array of organization detail object returned from the discovery service.</param>
    /// <returns>Organization details or null if the organization was not found.</returns>
    /// <seealso cref="DiscoveryOrganizations"/>
    public OrganizationDetail FindOrganization(string orgUniqueName,
        OrganizationDetail[] orgDetails)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orgUniqueName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("orgUniqueName");
        if (orgDetails == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("orgDetails");
        OrganizationDetail orgDetail = null;

        foreach (OrganizationDetail detail in orgDetails)
        {
            if (String.Compare(detail.UniqueName, orgUniqueName,
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                orgDetail = detail;
                break;
            }
        }
        return orgDetail;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generic method to obtain discovery/organization service proxy instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TService">
    /// Set IDiscoveryService or IOrganizationService type to request respective service proxy instance.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProxy">
    /// Set the return type to either DiscoveryServiceProxy or OrganizationServiceProxy type based on TService type.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <param name="serviceManagement">An instance of IServiceManagement</param>
    /// <param name="authCredentials">The user's Microsoft Dynamics CRM logon credentials.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp4>
    private TProxy GetProxy<TService, TProxy>(
        IServiceManagement<TService> serviceManagement,
        AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials)
        where TService : class
        where TProxy : ServiceProxy<TService>
    {
        Type classType = typeof(TProxy);

        if (serviceManagement.AuthenticationType !=
            AuthenticationProviderType.ActiveDirectory)
        {
            AuthenticationCredentials tokenCredentials =
                serviceManagement.Authenticate(authCredentials);
            // Obtain discovery/organization service proxy for Federated, LiveId and OnlineFederated environments. 
            // Instantiate a new class of type using the 2 parameter constructor of type IServiceManagement and SecurityTokenResponse.
            return (TProxy)classType
                .GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IServiceManagement<TService>), typeof(SecurityTokenResponse) })
                .Invoke(new object[] { serviceManagement, tokenCredentials.SecurityTokenResponse });
        }

        // Obtain discovery/organization service proxy for ActiveDirectory environment.
        // Instantiate a new class of type using the 2 parameter constructor of type IServiceManagement and ClientCredentials.
        return (TProxy)classType
            .GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IServiceManagement<TService>), typeof(ClientCredentials) })
            .Invoke(new object[] { serviceManagement, authCredentials.ClientCredentials });
    }
    /// </snippetAuthenticateWithNoHelp4>

    #endregion How To Sample Code

    #region Main method

    /// <summary>
    /// Standard Main() method used by most SDK samples.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AuthenticateWithNoHelp app = new AuthenticateWithNoHelp();
            app.Run();
        }
        catch (FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
            Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", ex.Detail.Timestamp);
            Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", ex.Detail.ErrorCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Detail.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Trace: {0}", ex.Detail.TraceText);
            Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                null == ex.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
        }
        catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
            Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                null == ex.InnerException.Message ? "No Inner Fault" : ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            // Display the details of the inner exception.
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);

                FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> fe = ex.InnerException
                    as FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>;
                if (fe != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", fe.Detail.Timestamp);
                    Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", fe.Detail.ErrorCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", fe.Detail.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Trace: {0}", fe.Detail.TraceText);
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                        null == fe.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
                }
            }
        }
        // Additional exceptions to catch: SecurityTokenValidationException, ExpiredSecurityTokenException,
        // SecurityAccessDeniedException, MessageSecurityException, and SecurityNegotiationException.

        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    #endregion Main method
}
```

}
//

As you can see it is more complex than getting IOrganizationService from `Microsoft.Xrm.Client` but should do its job in your case.

Of course this is generic code which will work in most scenarios, but if for example you have plain Windows Authentication, your code would be simplified to:

```
ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();

        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential( "login", "password", "domain" );

        string orgUrl = "http://ServerName/OrganizationName/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc";


        using(OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(orgUrl), null, credentials, null))
        {
            //use serviceProxy as IOrganizationService
        }
```

Comment: Hi Pawel,
I appreciate your answer, but it has 2 problems:
1) I cannot instanciate a long process like that every time I need to log a message on the CRM.
2) I cannot bind the credentials and the url in the code, as I can't change it passing from develop to production environment: any of these parameters are stored in an entity in the CRM, and I obviously I need a working service to read them...

Comment: It was not a part of initial question so I thought that you have figured that out already - where have you been storing CRMConnectionString in your previous solution? Because if previous solution was working for you, then this is exactly the same. like I said, OrganizationService that you were instantiating previously is doing the same logic that I posted in my answer - it simply takes all the necessary data from Connection string but under the hood the connection looks exactly like above (so instantiating organizationServiceProxy with proper parameters). Maybe share your connectionstring?

Comment: And one more thing - I agree that you should not do this when you are logging things in CRM, but you did it in your initial solution, and StackOverflow is not a place to complain about somebody's bad ideas, it's about solving problems. I'm sorry that it's not a single line of code right now, but it has exactly the same impact on performance like it had before with the CRMConnectionString version.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add an IOrganizationService field and a constructor to add the service on instantiation:

```
public class SFACMessageInspector : IEndpointBehavior, IClientMessageInspector
{
    private IOrganizationService service;

    public SFACMessageInspector(IOrganizationService svc)
    {
        service = svc;
    }
}
```

And then instantiate from the plugin:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    var factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    var crmService = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

    var interceptor = new SFACMessageInspector(crmService);
}
```

You should then be able to access `service` within the `BeforeSendRequest` and `AfterReceiveReply` methods, without having to pass it in as a parameter.

If you are still looking to work with the connection string method, the new way to do it is via the CrmServiceClient in the Xrm.Tooling.Connector assembly:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn688177.aspx

For example:

```
private IOrganizationService createService(string connectionString)
{
    return new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
}
```